ASP.NET Core MVC pass a url parameter to the POST
I have a Blazor Server app. It uses the ASP.NET Identity Library which is ASP.NET Core MVC. I am trying to pass a parameter to register so a URL like /identity/account/Register?follow=uniqueId gives me the parameter follow=uniqueId.
In Register.cshtml.cs (class RegisterModel) I have:
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null, string following = null)
{
    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    Following = following;
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null, string following = null)
{
    // ...
}

The value from the url is passed in to OnGetAsync() fine. But when OnPostAsync() is called, it passes in a null for following and the object property Following is also null.
How do I get that parameter in OnPostAsync()?

POST would expect those to bind from a form body.  For me I find it confusing to send query params in POST, but you can just set those explicitly to bind [FromQuery]  and then bind the body [FromForm].  If this is a JS POST of JSON data, you'd bind everything to [FromBody]... you won't be able to read query params though.  All data has to come from the body.

According to your description, the reason why the following is always null is you don't set the [FromQuery] attribute and not use the right query string.
Inside the url your querystring is follow not following which will not bind well.
I suggest you could modify the method like below:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null, [FromQuery]string following = null)
{
    // ...
}



Update:
As you said, POST requests do not automatically include URL parameters unless you set it inside the from action attribute.
Since you don't share how you post the request, I provide two way which could make this post work well.
More details, you could refer to below example:
1.You set the follow query string inside the form tag action like below:
<form action="/register?follow=uniqueId" method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="Submut"/>
    

</form>

2.If you are using the razor page and still want to use it, you could refer to below :
<form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" asp-route-follow="@Model.Follow">

3.If you are using the razor page and post it inside the razor page not blazor, you could use hidden field and use the bind parameter
like below:
<form method="post">

    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Following"  value="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submut" />


</form>

Inside the razor page.cs add below codes:
    [BindProperty]
    public string Following { get; set; }


That does not work. I'm guessing it's because the POST does not remember anything from the GET and the GET, to first display the page, is where following is set.

Yes, POST requests do not automatically include URL parameters unless you set it inside the from action attribute. Please see my update answer.

Make sense. Because backend expect to have these values as parameters in url. You always can add [FromBody] attribute to the parameters in your controller. But it works funky with simple types.
Example:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody] string returnUrl = null, [FromBody] string following = null)
{
  ...
}

I would recommend to wrap your data into an object, let's say:
public class MyData
{
  public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
  public string Following { get; set; }
}

Then modify your post method to:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody] MyData myData)
{
  ...
}

Downside of this modification is that you need to modify your front-end to wrap your strings into MyData format.
Additional information about parameter binding in ASP.NET:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

That will not work for me because it needs to be in the URL. thanks - dave
